# Drawing a longer line with Tikz

Tags: diagrams, tikz-arrows

Using tikz, I've drawn the following line:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% draw horizontal line   
\draw (0,0) -- (10,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

yet it covers only slightly more than half the page. How can I make the line longer while retaining the number (10) of segments?

Comment: Make page narrower? Seriously, what is wrong with `\draw (0,0) -- (\textwidth,0);?

Comment: you can change the unit vector: `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.3cm,y=1.3cm]`

Comment: The line is drawn as a one line, it's not drawn as segments! So `\draw(0,0)--(20,0);` is still just one line.

Comment: What do you mean by segments? There are no segments. It's one straight horizontal line of length 10. (By default that's 10cm.) Unless you changed anything you don't show us. And you haven't shown us much.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it is not entirely clear what you after. In the case, that just one line drawn between `(0,0)` and `(10,0)` has length equal to `\textwidth`, than you can for this line consider @cfr comment:

- If you like to extend just one line to `\textwidth`, than you can write

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{geometry}  & page layout is unknown ...
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[x=\linewidth/10] (0,0)--(10,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- In the case, that this line has scale, than it should be slightly narrower that scale can be in the page text area. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{geometry}  & page layout is unknown ...
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\scoped[x=\linewidth/10-1pt]
{
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0)--(10,0);
\foreach \x in {0,...,10}
    \draw (\x,2mm) -- ++ (0,-4mm) node[below] {\x};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(in bot images red lines indicate page layout)

In above cases you should be aware, that rest of image content will for unit vector consider `x=1, y=1`. Is this ok to you? If not and you like that unit vector is ``x=\linewidth/10, y=1`, than scaling in the second example move to from` scoped`environment to`tikzpicture` options:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{geometry}  & page layout is unknown ...
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\linewidth/10-1pt, y=1]
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0)--(10,0);
\foreach \x in {0,...,10}
    \draw (\x,2mm) -- ++ (0,-4mm) node[below] {\x};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, in such cases you should be aware, that all drawn elements of your picture will be deformed in `x` direction.

Answer (score 0):

You have the two segments (and scales
) with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=2pt] (0,0)--(10,0);
        \foreach \n in {0,1,...,10}
            \draw (\n,.05)--(\n,-.05) node[below] () {\n};
        \draw[line width=2pt,scale=1.5,blue] (0,1)--(10,1);
        \foreach \n in {0,1,...,10}
            \draw[scale=1.5] (\n,1.05)--(\n,.95) node[below] () {\n};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The black segment (shorter) is not scaled and is drawn only for confrontation.
You can take only the code you need:

```
\draw[line width=2pt,scale=1.5,blue] (0,1)--(10,1);
        \foreach \n in {0,1,...,10}
            \draw[scale=1.5] (\n,1.05)--(\n,.95) node[below] () {\n};
```

if you want the scale.

Or only this one:

```
\draw[line width=2pt,scale=1.5,blue] (0,1)--(10,1);
```

if you dont need the scale.